# How node modules are included in an angular-cli build?

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

Can somebody please explain me, how we include node modules in an @angular/cli build, how do we load our code's third party libraries ?

Answer (score 0):

in .angular-cli.json include the path of node module like this:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",  
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/cupertino/theme.css", 
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" ]
```

if you want to add script replace "styles" with "scripts".

Comment: and after adding the modules in angular-cli.json will they be minified ?

Comment: they get minified once you make the build.

Comment: @JitenderKumar Then what about the modules which are directly installed via npm install and used in app.module.